# Make python display help screen if no action is given

Tags: python

Let's say a user runs the script w/o giving any paramters. How can I make it so that it defaults to `./myscript.py -h` so that it shows them the help info?

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-d", "--directory", metavar="DIR",
                    help="Directory to scan for big files")
parser.add_option("-e", "--email", metavar='EMAIL', 
                    help='email to send the list to')
parser.add_option("-l", "--limit", metavar='LIMIT', 
                    help='return number of files')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    parser.print_help()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if len(argv) == 0:
    parser.print_help()
```